# How to wait in a loop on mouseover and not put all events in call stack JS / Vue.js

Tags: loops, vue.js, wait, onmouseover

I do an api call at each mouseover but I need to wait one second and perform a single api call according to the last mouseover.

Ex. If the user mouseover on 10 titles, the api call will be done only after his mouse stay one second on.

Here's a fiddle to illustrate (cf. network in inspector) : https://codesandbox.io/s/search-a-la-mano-hpk92

Comment: Solved : Fiddle edited with aquilesb solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lodash.debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) for that. It just will call after the time you have passed. It only will execute the function within the last call parameters, avoiding unnecessary calls. You can check an example [here](https://codepen.io/brav0/pen/dZNMmW).

You only have to wrap your function with the `debouce` function

```js
debounce(
  function (param1) { console.log('hello' + param1)},
  500
)
```

Comment: Actually, I think it prevents, You can take a look in those two examples. https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/MMxoeP
https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-bounce-mqe3p

Comment: Thanks  a lot aquilesb, you made my day !

Answer (score 0):

So, there is "mouseleave" which only triggeres, when the user has left the element.

```
myElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
```

And the event object delivers some information about its behavior. With `event.relatedTarget` you get the element on which the mouse were before.

Dunno if this helps but you can try it

Comment: Thanks thissven but it doesn't prevent event to be queued in call stack